# Zapier displaying no data while trying to integrate google sheets with slack

Tags: google-sheets, automation, slack, zapier

My google sheet on drive has some formulas. The resultant formaula is at the end. When I am trying to access data using zap, no data is being displayed. I tried using formatter but its not working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would be a really good question to write into their support about as they'd have a bit more context and can see the entire Zap!